# How to Route Replies to Salesforce Email Alerts Back into Salesforce Instead of Outlook Inbox?

Tags: email, case, servicecloud, email-alert

I am facing a challenge with email alerts in Service Cloud and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Context: A flow sends an email alert to the customer. The customer receives the email from the automated case user (automatedUser@abc.com).
The issue arises when customers reply to these email alerts, they are replying to automatedUser@abc.com which doesnt send the email back to Salesforce.

I need a way to ensure that when customers reply to the email alerts sent by Salesforce, these replies are routed back into Salesforce instead of an Outlook inbox. Do I need to set up an org wide email address for this? and do I need a new email address for this i.e. info@abc.com ? or am I going down the wrong path?

Any help would be appreciated. For info, this is not in the live environment, it is in a testing environment.

Support Settings for info:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated the "From Email Address" on the Email Alert.